# Conway( A Course in Functional Analysis) Proposition 3.3

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to solve that if  $\|L\|:=sup \{ |L(h)| :\|h\| \leq 1 \}$ then $\|L\|= sup \{ |L(h)| :\| h\| =1 \}$. We know that $L$ is a bounded linear functional.I know that it is solved if we suppose $\{h_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\| h_n \| \leq 1 $ and with $lim |L(h_n)|=sup \{ |L(h)| :\|h\| \leq 1 \} $ but I want another way to solve.I think it is better to prove the following statement
$$sup \{|L(h)|:\|h\|<1\}=sup \{|L(h)|:\|h\|≤1\}$$
I can prove with get limit ( we suppose $\{h_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\|h_n\|≤1$ and with $lim|L(h_n)|=sup\{|L(h)|:\|h\|≤1\}$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please write what you tried. I hope you at least see why one of the two required inequalities hold.

Comment: I think it is better to prove the following statement     $$sup \{ |L(h)| :\|h\| < 1 \}= sup \{ |L(h)| :\|h\| \leq 1 \}$$                            I can prove with get lim (   we suppose $\{h_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\| h_n \| \leq 1 $ and with $lim |L(h_n)|=sup \{ |L(h)| :\|h\| \leq 1 \} $) but I want another way

Comment: You can use \sup, \lim, \cos and many more in LaTex (with a space after the last letter) so they don't get italic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{|L(h)|:\|h\|<1\}.$ Let $B=\{|L(h')|:\|h'\|=1\}.$

Obviously we have $$\sup A\le \sup B$$ because $L$ is linear. And $0\le\sup B<\infty$ because $L$ is bounded and because $B\ne\emptyset.$

Given $\epsilon \in (0,1),$ take $h'$ with $\|h')\|=1$ such that $|L(h')|\ge (1-\epsilon /2)\sup B.$ Let $h=(1-\epsilon /2)h'.$ Then $\|h\|<1$. We have $$\sup A\ge |L(h)|=(1-\epsilon /2)|L(h')| \ge (1-\epsilon /2)^2\sup B\ge (1-\epsilon)\sup B.$$ So $\sup A\ge (1-\epsilon)\sup B$  for any $\epsilon\in (0,1).$ So we must have $$\sup A\ge \sup B.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $r>0$ let $$M_r=\sup \{|L(h)|\,:\,\|h\|=r\}$$
By linearity we have $M_r=rM_1.$ Furthermore
$$\sup \{|L(h)|\,:\,\|h\|<1\} =\sup_{0<r<1} M_r= \sup_{0<r<1} rM_1=M_1= \sup \{|L(h)|\,:\,\|h\|=1\}$$